# Rolling window for averaging using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have the following code, pasted below. I would like to change it to only average the 10 most recently filtered images and not the entire group of filtered images. The line I think I need to change is: `Yout(k,p,q) = (Yout(k,p,q)  + (y.^2))/2;`, but how do I do it?

```
j=1;
K = 1:3600;
window = zeros(1,10);
Yout = zeros(10,column,row);
figure;
y = 0;                           %# Preallocate memory for output
%Load one image
for i = 1:length(K)
    disp(i)
    str = int2str(i);
    str1 = strcat(str,'.mat');
    load(str1);
    D{i}(:,:) = A(:,:);

    %Go through the columns and rows
    for p = 1:column
        for q = 1:row
            if(mean2(D{i}(p,q))==0)
                x = 0;
            else
                if(i == 1)
                    meanvalue = mean2(D{i}(p,q));
                end

                %Calculate the temporal mean value based on previous ones.
                meanvalue = (meanvalue+D{i}(p,q))/2;
                x = double(D{i}(p,q)/meanvalue);
            end
            %Filtering for 10 bands, based on the previous state
            for k = 1:10
                [y, ZState{k}] = filter(bCoeff{k},aCoeff{k},x,ZState{k});
                Yout(k,p,q) = (Yout(k,p,q)  + (y.^2))/2;
            end
        end
    end
    %     for k = 2:10
    %         subplot(5,2,k)
    %         subimage(Yout(k)*5000, [0 100]);
    %         colormap jet
    %     end
    %     pause(0.01);
end
disp('Done Loading...')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this (in my opinion) would be to use a circular-buffer to store your images. In a circular-, or ring-buffer, the oldest data element in the array is overwritten by the newest element pushed in to the array. The basics of making such a structure are described in the short Mathworks video *[Implementing a simple circular buffer](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/05/08/implementing-a-simple-circular-buffer/)*.

For each iteration of you main loop that deals with a single image, just load a new image into the circular-buffer and then use [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)'s built in `mean` function to take the average efficiently.

If you need to apply a window function to the data, then make a temporary copy of the frames multiplied by the window function and take the average of the copy at each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Yout(k,p,q) = (Yout(k,p,q)  + (y.^2))/2;
```

calculates a kind of [Moving Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) for each of the 10 bands over all your images.
This line calculates a moving average of `meanvalue` over your images:

```
meanvalue=(meanvalue+D{i}(p,q))/2;
```

For both you will want to add a buffer structure that keeps only the last 10 images. 
To simplify it, you can also just keep all in memory. Here is an example for `Yout`:

Change this line: (Add one dimension)

```
Yout = zeros(3600,10,column,row);
```

And change this:

```
for q = 1:row            

    [...]

    %filtering for 10 bands, based on the previous state
    for k = 1:10
        [y, ZState{k}] = filter(bCoeff{k},aCoeff{k},x,ZState{k});
        Yout(i,k,p,q) = y.^2;
    end

    YoutAvg = zeros(10,column,row);
    start = max(0, i-10+1);
    for avgImg = start:i
        YoutAvg(k,p,q) = (YoutAvg(k,p,q) + Yout(avgImg,k,p,q))/2;
    end
end
```

Then to display use

```
subimage(Yout(k)*5000, [0 100]);
```

You would do sth. similar for `meanvalue`